# Python String Replace closest value to the search value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace a string here in Python. I want the period and the closest character to the left of it to be deleted.

This is my Input

```
test = "1. 4 7 2. 5 0 3. 223 1 4. 3 17 5. 57 0 6. 7 6 "
```

I want output to by like this

```
test = " 4 7  5 0  223 1  3 17  57 0  7 6 "
```

I was able to remove the dot, but I don't know how to remove the character before the dot?

I tried it:

`print(test.replace('.', ''))`

Answer (score 1):

```
test = "1. 4 7 2. 5 0 3. 223 1 4. 3 17 5. 57 0 6. 7 6 "
new_test = []
for number in test.split(" "):
    if "." not in number:
        new_test.append(number)
new_test = " ".join(new_test)
print(new_test)
```

This works exactly like You want. First create new list where you store correct numbers (without dots). Then iterate over splitted "test" and when number doesn't contain '.', append it to the new list.

Comment: FWIW, you can replace this with a one-liner: `' ' + ' '.join([number for number in test.split(' ') if '.' not in number])` - including the extra space at the start and end.

Comment: Yeah, it can be shortened of course, but I wanted to make it 100% clear for OP :P

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression `sub` command.

```
import re
test = "1. 4 7 2. 5 0 3. 223 1 4. 3 17 5. 57 0 6. 7 6 "
print(re.sub(r'\d*[.]', '', test))  # ->  4 7  5 0  223 1  3 17  57 0  7 6
```